# View the source code C++ in Eclipse - Ubuntu environtment

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

I had loaded the project to Eclipse but when I open the .cpp file, it like to open a text file.
Anyone know how to display the code-view in eclipse?
Please support.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Code is text. Or am I missing something?  `\(o.O)/`

Comment: Single file: right click, `open with`, select `C/C++ editor`.

Comment: Oh, have you CDT installed at all? Normally, C/C++ editor should already be associated with these files.

Comment: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `FileTypes`: C and C++ file endings should have `locked` status.

Comment: @JoeyMallone It is - but eclipse provides different editors for different types of text files, among these one for C and C++ source files - which is what in eclipse provides all the support an IDE normally comes with (syntax highlighting, symbol lookup, code completion, auto-formatting, etc).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I cannot find C/C++ in Window -> Preferences. What I missing? And how can I include C/C++ to Window -> Preferences. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find C/C++ in Window -> Preferences

Then you have no CDT installed – I suppose you got the version direct from the initial [download page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), but that's actually the java package – there's a link ['download packages'](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) below, where you would have found the C++ package. Not too obvious, admitted.

Never mind, you don't need to re-install:  `Help` -> `About` will reveil you your installed version's name ('Kepler', 'Luna', ...); via `Help` -> `Install new packages` you can add CDT plugin to your installation. Select under `work with` your release version of eclipse repository, e. g. `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon`.

Minimally, you need: `C/C++ Development Tools`, other plugins might be useful, too, like standalone debugger, call graph visualisation, unit testing support, auto tools support (configure, make; especially under linux), possibly LLVM support (if you want to use clang compiler), ...

Comment: Thank you so much @Aconcagua. My issue had been solved.

Answer (score 0):

My issue had been fixed.
Just do below steps in ubuntu:

1. Go to 
   https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php and download newest CDT(C/C++ Develop Tool) version.
2. Copy the download file

> eclipse-cpp-2018-12-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

to your folder in Ubuntu.

3. Extract

> eclipse-cpp-2018-12-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

4. Run execute eclipse file -> Done.

Comment: Hm, complete re-install - wouldn't actually have been necessary... On the other hand, likely to be the simplest solution (at least, if you do not yet use other packages). Be aware, though, that you can have multiple different plugins installed at the same time, so if you want to support another language (e. g. python, perl, ... - even latex is possible), too (without maintaining separate installations for each), then remember the `Install new packages` feature.